# Rails 7: Loading all Stimulus controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, ruby-on-rails-7, hotwire-rails

I've recently upgraded my app from Rails 6 to Rails 7, but some items seem to have changed with how Stimulus controllers are loaded from `javascript/controllers`.

I Rails 6 I was able to do this from an `index.js` file in the `javascript/controllers` directory:

```js
const context = require.context("controllers", true, /_controller\.js$/)
application.load(definitionsFromContext(context))
```

However in Rails 7 this raises (in my browsers js console):

```
Uncaught TypeError: __require.context is not a function
```

So I'm stuck calling this for each of my Stimulus controllers:

```
import FooBarController from "./foo_bar_controller"
application.register("foo_bar_controller", FooBarController)
```

What is the right way to import and register all my Stimulus controllers in Rails 7? I cannot find any details on this in the docs.

**UPDATE:**

I ran the stimulus:install rake task, and it did change some of my files that I had that were previously incorrect.  However now when I build the app I get this:

```
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "controllers/application"
    app/javascript/controllers/index.js:3:28:
      3 │ import { application } from "controllers/application"
        ╵                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  You can mark the path "controllers/application" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error.
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "@hotwired/stimulus-loading"
    app/javascript/controllers/index.js:6:41:
      6 │ import { eagerLoadControllersFrom } from "@hotwired/stimulus-loading"
        ╵                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  You can mark the path "@hotwired/stimulus-loading" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error.
```

This is what I have in my importmap.rb file as well:

```
pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
```

Comment: did you run `rails stimulus:install`, that should amend your `application.js` to register the stimulus controllers: https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus-rails

Comment: Tony, yes I reran that, and that DID actually help somewhat, although it seems to not understand where I'm importing the JS from still, updated to add more detail.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This depends on what you're currently using as a JavaScript bundler/builder.

The [Stimulus Handbook](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/handbook/installing) explains the different methods of installation and autoloading controllers in Rails.

`require.context` was only available through webpack. This has been replaced with Hotwire+Stimulus in Rails 7 (and optionally [importmap](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails)).

It sounds like you're currently on esbuild, so you should be able to update the `index.js` controller imports using the command `rails stimulus:manifest:update`.

This may require that you run `rails stimulus:install` first.

Comment: Looks like this led me in the right direction, thanks.